# iPad screen locks up

Tags: ipad

My iPad air2, locks up usually once a day...when rotate, screen stays in either the landscape or portrait made. Have to force off. Ok when I turn it back on. 2 years old, this started in past month or so.

Comment: Have you checked either the hardware witch or the software switch for rotation lock?

Comment: I have this exact same problem on my iPad air 2. the rotation lock switch is turned of and can be switched on and off again without effect.
turning it of or resetting the device fixes it for a day or two but then it locks up again.